# CakePHP: $form->input('checkbox');

Tags: cakephp

with config div => false

```
$form->input('checkbox');
```

print

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" ....>
<label>checkbox</label>
```

but i want it reverse order

```
<label>checkbox</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" ....>
```

can it reverse ?

Comment: This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34055976/cakephp-3-x-checkbox-formatting-issue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a neater way of doing this than the method ShiVik posted. That forced you to manually enter the title to checkbox inside of a  tag. If you don't want that, there's a method to re-arrange the order of elements.

In your example, you simply want to change the order of the $format option, like so:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('checkbox', array(
                                  'type'=>'checkbox', 
                                  'format' => array('before', 'input', 'between', 'label', 'after', 'error' ) 
  ) ); ?>
```

- Edit, just noticed your post was running cake 1.2. This code is for cake 1.3

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by setting the label to false and using the option "before" to display the label where you want.

```
<?php echo $form->input('checkbox', 
    array(
      'label'=>false, 
      'type'=>'checkbox',
      'before' => '<label>checkbox</lablel>', 
      'div' => false
 )); ?>
```

Useful links

- http://book.cakephp.org/view/191/options-before-options-between-options-separator-a
- http://book.cakephp.org/view/196/options-label

If not this, then you can use the [Form element specific methods](http://book.cakephp.org/view/204/Form-Element-Specific-Methods), instead of the [automagic form elements](http://book.cakephp.org/view/189/Automagic-Form-Elements).

Comment: And that's exactly why I prefer the Form element specific methods, instead of wrestling with the options array. ;) Valid answer nonetheless.

Comment: it dont wrestling with options array if checkbox can reverse easily.
With inputDefault , you can config fast

Answer (score 1):

It's often easier to do things manually if the generic `FormHelper::input` wrapper doesn't fit your bill:

```
echo $form->label('fieldname');
echo $form->checkbox('fieldname');
```

I often don't use `FormHelper::input` beyond scaffolding.

Comment: sorry but I often use table in form :D

Comment: @meotim And why does that prevent you from writing it this way?