# CakePHP 3.x checkbox formatting issue

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

This may seem obvious to some of you, but I really am struggling to find a straight answer. I've generally googled, as well as read both the CakePHP manual and the API for an answer to the following question:

When creating an input, the following code creates the following outputs:

```
// in the view
echo $this->Form->input('notes');

// resultant html
<div class="input textarea">
    <label for="notes">Notes</label>
    <textarea id="notes" rows="5" name="notes"></textarea>
</div>
```

Note: this is consistent across most input types; and because it's consistent it's great for formatting.

However, with a checkbox:

```
//In the view
echo $this->Form->input('ticket_required', 
    ['type' => 'checkbox']
);

// resultant HTML
<div class="input checkbox">
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="ticket_required">
    <label for="ticket-required">
    <input id="ticket-required" type="checkbox" value="1" name="ticket_required">
    Ticket Required</label>
</div>
```

[Note: I understand the need/desire for the hidden field]

Now.. *surely* it can't be an uncommon requirement to simply want the same format approach as every other standard input?

My question - how do I make CakePHP create a checkbox element as follows:

```
// desired HTML
<div class="input checkbox">
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="ticket_required">
    <label for="ticket-required">
    Ticket Required</label>
    <input id="ticket-required" type="checkbox" value="1" name="ticket_required">
</div>
```

To be clear: the order of visible elements is the same as other generated elements (label before input, and all encased in the wrapping div).

Please note.. i have tried the `'nestedInput' => false` option. This actually gets rid of the checkbox input entirely from the div.

I can't understand why this isn't done that way... but even if it was, I can't fathom why this isn't an obvious question for the documentation.

Oh well.. hopefully someone can help me here.

Thanks in advance.

Rick

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5394069/3144159

Comment: This doesn't work on CakePHP 3.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have thought the `nestedInput` would work but even if it did, you don't want to add that to every input you create throughout the website.

CakePHP 3 uses [string templates](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses) to build form controls.  [You can modify them to suit your needs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#customizing-the-templates-formhelper-uses).

By default the checkbox is using the `nestingLabel` template so if you want to stop all inputs from being nested you can change the template.

```
// src/View/AppView.php

$this->loadView('Form', [
    templates => [
        'nestingLabel' => '<label{{attrs}}>{{text}}</label>{{hidden}}{{input}}'
    ],
    // [More helper default config overrides][2]..
])
```

For more control over your helpers you can [create your own](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers) that extends one of the core helpers.